# Fast multiplication of 64bit integer taking modulo using 64bit integer without overflow

Tags: java, modulo

I want Fast multiplication of 64bit integer taking modulo using 64bit integer without overflow.
I know two way to calculate multiplication of 64bit integer taking modulo.

1. Use BigInteger
2. Calculate like

```
long mul(long a, long b){
  if(a==1)return b;
  else if(a%2==0)return 2*mul(a/2,b)%mod;
  else return (mul(a-1,b)+b)%mod;
}
```

However both way is slower compared to C++'s __int128_t.

My idea is to divide a and b to 32 bit integer and calculate them.
For example, multiplication is

(a_0+a_1 2^{32})(b_0+b_1 2^{32})=a_0 b_0+(a_0 b_1+a_1 b_0)2^{32}+a_1 b_1 2^{64}

.But I don't know how to take modulo fast.

If you have good idea, please help me.

Comment: What is `mod`? What is `f(...)`?

Comment: f(...) is typo of mul(...).

Comment: Still doesn't say what `mod` is. --- If the method is supposed to just calculate the multiplication of `a` and `b`, why isn't `return a*b;` fast enough for you? --- If the method is supposed to return the 128-bit result of multiplying two 64-bit values, why is the return value a 64-bit `long`? --- Your question is not making any sense.

Comment: Normally, you would leave this kind of optimization to the compiler/interpreter, do you have a reason for doing this?

Comment: mod is some constant 64bit integer value.

Comment: If a, b, mod are 64 bit integer value, a*b%mod is also 64 bit integer value. However, a*b can exceed 64bit integer although it will eventually 64bit integer after taking modulo mod. Thus, we need some trick to calculate a*b%mod without overflow.

Comment: "Normally, you would leave this kind of optimization to the compiler/interpreter, do you have a reason for doing this?" I know two way to calculate a*b%mod. However it's too slow. Thus, the optimization of the compiler/interpreter is not enough.